# Ajax call is being accidently triggered

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a login page and at the bottom of the pop-up form, there is another button that takes you to the registration page. The issue appears to be that when navigating to the new page it all sits under the original sign-in form which uses an ajax call to check if the user exists so when they try to submit the registration form it then calls that ajax call from the sign-in form.

Sign-in form

```
<div id="myForm">    
    <form onsubmit="return false;" id="loginForm">
        <h1>Login</h1>

        <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

        <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" id="psw" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
        <div id="message" class="alert-danger"></div>
        <br />
        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm();">Close</button>
    </form>
    <div class="d-inline">            
        <button class="btn-info">@Html.ActionLink("User Registration", "SignUp", "SignUp_SignIn")</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then the ajax call is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("form").on('submit', function (event) {
            var data = {
                'email': $("#email").val(),
                'psw': $("#psw").val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'SignUp_SignIn/CredentialCheck',
                data: data,
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result == true) {
                            $("#message").text("Login attempt was successful");
                    }
                    else {
                            $("#message").text("Email/Password didn't match any results");
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("It failed");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: How many forms do you have on the page? And this `$("form").on('submit')` is bound to all forms.

Comment: I believe issue occurred for this <button class="btn-info">@Html.ActionLink("User Registration", "SignUp", "SignUp_SignIn")</button>
@Html.ActionLink return `a` tag. and if you not add type attribute in button by default it's consider `submit type`.

Comment: Can you share whole page along with register form that is creating the issue?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the comments I realized that the reason that the login form was being called from the layout.cshtml so when the ajax call was being called it was grabbing all the form tags that existed on any page that was loaded up. After changing the ajax so it was calling a specific `id` for the login form instead of `form` it allowed for proper actions to take place.

An example of what I'm refusing to

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("form").on('submit', function (event) {            
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: data,
                success: function (result) {
                    //Do stuff
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

The above will try to redirect you on the submit of any form that is loaded up, but if we go through and change the way it accesses the form like below then it will only work if the one specific form is submitted.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#loginForm").on('submit', function (event) {            
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: data,
                success: function (result) {
                    //Do stuff
                }
            });
        });
    });
```